# Use variable in for loop as a selector?

Tags: stylus

Is something like this possible?

```
for my_class_selector in _aClass _bClass _cClass _dClass _eClass ... 
    .my_class_selector
        display none
```

Basically I want to create a bunch of classes with similar properties...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just needed the curly braces

```
for my_class_selector in _aClass _bClass _cClass _dClass _eClass
    .{my_class_selector}
        display none
```